# Is it possible to change the layout width and height in Android at run time?

Tags: android

I have two relative layouts. Both have width of fill parent and height of 100 dip. My requirement is when I click the first layout it should shrink to 50dip height and the other expand to the 150dip height. While doing this I got exception. Please help me how to change the layout width and height at run time.

```
    final LinearLayout RLChange = new LinearLayout(this);        
    RLChange.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
    RLChange.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final LinearLayout RLGreen = new LinearLayout(this);        
    RLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             300));
    RLGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    RLGreen.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    Button btnClick = new Button(this);        
    btnClick.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    RLGreen.addView(btnClick);


    final LinearLayout RLYellow = new LinearLayout(this);        
    RLYellow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             200));
    RLYellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View view) {  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
        }
     });  

    RLChange.addView(RLGreen);
    RLChange.addView(RLYellow);
    setContentView(RLChange);




Log Cat


03-10 11:01:35.328: INFO/NotificationService(574): enqueueToast pkg=Changewidth.com callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43948648 duration=0
03-10 11:01:35.388: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1505): Shutting down VM
03-10 11:01:35.388: WARN/dalvikvm(1505): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
03-10 11:01:35.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:326)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:747)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1613)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
03-10 11:01:35.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 11:01:35.479: INFO/Process(574): Sending signal. PID: 1505 SIG: 3
03-10 11:01:35.479: INFO/dalvikvm(1505): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-10 11:01:35.619: INFO/dalvikvm(1505): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-10 11:01:35.779: DEBUG/dalvikvm(623): GC freed 3557 objects / 196272 bytes in 448ms
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In onClick Listener add this code.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
LinearLayout rLGreen = ((LinearLayout) button.getParent());
rLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

It will work.

Answer (score 8):

Hi you can change the width and height of your layout using this code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
lauout1.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: but when I change the layout parameters at run time the application crashes :(

Comment: same code as u mentioned above. But when I change the width at run time, the app crashes

Comment: Please debug the code and check in which line error comes and share the stacktrace.

Comment: Hi..please let me know how to add code here. I couldn't find a way to do it

Comment: edit in your question which u hv ashed and enter the code (check the toolbar options "{}").

Comment: In your code you have declared RLGreen an final.  you have to create new instance of layout by id in button's onClick code then change its layoutParameter.

Comment: Is it possible to shrink the existing layout, without creating a new one inside the OnClick listener?

Comment: yes you can. get layout from xml using findViewById() inside the onClick listener.

Comment: I tried all method.. but application crashed while changing the layout width at run time.. :(

Comment: have you debug your code. In which line you are getting error?? and add your logcat.

Comment: RLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: If i have a child inside `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` in width and modify the width from `RelativeLayout`, how can update the width of child?

Answer (score 2):

These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many subclasses of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and these correspond to the different subclasses of `ViewGroup` that are responsible for arranging their children.

So basically, if you are adding a view to another, you MUST set the `LayoutParams` of the view to the `LayoutParams` type that the parent uses or you will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct LayoutParams class for your particular view? Try using LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the LayoutParams are use by the Parent(viewgroup of parent) in order to determine how to layout this View.

Thus for example if you have the following

```
LinearLayout
    RelativeLayout1
    RelativeLayout2
```

And you want to change the width or height of the RelativeLayout1 or RelativeLayout2, 
then you need to do something like this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200);
//Get handle to RelativeLayout1 assuming it is R1, you would call
R1.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You would need to do the same to change RelativeLayout2's LayoutParams also.

Is is easy to forget the hierarchy, and to assume that you need to set the layout of the child, but it is the parent that determines what attributes are supported (eg. Alignment, or gravity etc..)

Hope this helps.  It has burned me a few times....